# Как задать правильное кэширование для файла .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, кэширование

Под правильным я понимаю такое, которое проходит метрики Google PageSpeed / Вот мой варинт файла .htaccess

```
# Кеширование
<ifModule mod_expires.c>

# Add correct content-type for fonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff2
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

# Compress compressible fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-opentype image/svg+xml

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"

# Cache Images
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 26 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 6 months"

# Cache Fonts
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff2 "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 2592000 seconds"

# Cache other content types (Flash, CSS, JS, HTML, XML)

ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 6 months"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"

</ifModule>
```

При таком раскладе у меня ругается на следующие файлы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я указываю не верно ?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас Apache, то все указываете верно... может понадобится время чтобы изменения вступили в силу. Редко но тоже бывает, не установлен на сервере mod_expires.c модуль, который отвечает за кеширование...